# Number of ways to pick at least x balls (balls are identical)?

Tags: python-2.7, permutation, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinators

There are N distinct boxes of balls in total. There are P boxes each containing A number of balls and remaining Q boxes contains B number of balls each.

Given a number X, what are the total the number of ways in which you can pick at least X balls from the boxes.

P+Q = N

Example: `Number of P boxes=2` which contain 2 balls each, `Number of Q boxes=1` which contain 2 balls. `X=3(Given)` where `x=minimum number of balls to be picked`
So, P+Q=3 (total number of boxes)
Combinations for the number of ways to pick atleast x i.e. 3 balls would be:

> combinations of 3:(111),(210),(120),(021),(012),(201),(102)
>   combinations of 4:(220)(202)(022)(211)(121)(112)
>   combinations of 5:(212)(122)(221)
>   combinations of 6: (222)
>   total Combinations: 17

My Approach:
I have used "Stars and Bars Approach":

> To calculate combinations of 6: x+y+z=6 which is converted into (2-x)+(2-y)+(2-z)=6 giving out x+y+z=0.
>   So, the combination of 6 becomes Binomial(2C2)=1
>   Similarly, Combinations of 5 becomes Binomial(3C2)=3
>   Combinations of 4= Binomial(4C2)=6
>  
>   Combinations of 3= Binomial(5C2)=10

```
1+3+6+10=20
but the answer should be 1+3+6+7=17
```

Edge case has appeared on calculating the combinations of 3. How should I tackle this problem?

EDIT: CODE ADDED in python

```
global total_combinations
total_combinations=0

from math import factorial

def combinations(a):
    global total_combinations
    bars=numberofAs+numberofBs-1
    stars=a
    total_combinations+=factorial(stars+bars)/(factorial(bars)*factorial(stars))


numberofAs,numberofBs,numberofballsinA,numberofballsinB=map(int,raw_input().split())

x=int(raw_input())

operational_array=[]

for i in range(numberofAs):
    operational_array.append(numberofballsinA)

for i in range(numberofBs):
    operational_array.append(numberofballsinB)

max_x=sum(operational_array) #calculate combinations from x to max_x
k=max_x

for i in range(max_x,x-1,-1):
    k=max_x-i
    combinations(k)

print total_combinations
```

Comment: wouldnt https://math.stackexchange.com/ be a better site for this?

Comment: @Demonking28 Where? I dont see any code, I dont see any Programming language specified, I dont see any attempt for an mcve...

Comment: @PatrickArtner True, but it looks like the question is a subtask of the problem.

Comment: Why do your example boxes have the same amount of balls in them? Are A and B distinct numbers? What if A = 100 and B = 200 balls, and P and Q are >10 each and you have to pick 2 balls. gotta be a huge number....

Comment: @john The stars and bars approach would fail because it will count the solutions (3 0 0)(0 3 0)(0 0 3) which are out of constraint since at max they can have 2 balls each.

Comment: @PatrickArtner Yes, A and B can be Distinct. If A holds 100 then according to the Example provided above, Number of A's are two and Number of B's are 1. The combinations would be made from (100 100 2)

Comment: @Demonking28 So, What should I do to eliminate these 3 extra combinations?

Comment: @johnmich I have a solution to the problem.But I am running out of time at this point in time.Will update shortly.

Comment: @RoryDaulton Now, I have added my python code as well.

Comment: Unless you _want_ to make your code hard to understand and debug, I don't see any point in using `global` in this example.

Answer (score 1):

The number of balls you can take *out* of a box containing A balls is the number of balls you can put *into* an empty box of capacity A.
There are known formulas for that problem.

If all boxes have the same number of balls initially (as in the given example, in which A=B=2),
and that number is equal to or greater than the total number of balls to be removed from the boxes, then "stars and bars" will work.
But if the number of balls to be removed is greater than the number in a single box, there is an iterative formula to find the number of ways the balls can be selected.
To remove `t` balls from `k` boxes containing `m` balls each,

```
from scipy.special import comb

def combinations_with_limit(t, k, m):
    total = 0
    max_full_boxes = min(k, int(t/(m + 1)))
    for i in range(max_full_boxes + 1):
        total += int((-1)**i) * comb(k, i, exact=True) * comb(t + k - 1 - i*(m + 1), k - 1, exact=True)
    return total
```

This is based on the formula [in this math.stackexchange answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/89425), but using `t` rather than `n` for the total number of balls removed in order to avoid confusion with the use of N in this question.
You can optimize and improve the style of this code, of course
(for example, I wouldn't suggest writing `int((-1)**i)` in production code);
the reason it's written this way is to stay as close as practical to the format of the MSE answer.

Not surprisingly, we have to think a little harder in the case where A and B are different.
To remove a total of `t` balls from `p` boxes containing `a` balls each and `q` boxes containing `b` balls each,

```
def combinations_with_two_limits(t, p, q, a, b):
    total = 0
    min_balls_from_p = max(0, t - q*b)
    max_balls_from_p = min(t, p*a)
    for i in range(min_balls_from_p, max_balls_from_p + 1):
        total += combinations_with_limit(i, p, a) * combinations_with_limit(t - i, q, b)
    return total
```

The idea here is that you first decide how to allocate the `t` balls into two groups, one to be removed from the boxes containing `a` balls and the other to be removed from the boxes containing `b` balls, 
and then count all the ways you can select those subsets of the balls from those subsets of the boxes.
It may be possible to optimize the code further by going back to the derivation of the MSE formula cited above (either through generating functions or the inclusion-exclusion principle), but I wouldn't try it unless it's really critical to shave a few percentage points off the running time.

To remove at least X balls from the boxes, take the sum of the values of
`combinations_with_two_limits` as `t` takes on all integer values from X up to and including the largest number of balls you can remove
(which is `P*A + Q*B`).

Answer (score 0):

Break it in 2 parts where you pick *k* balls from the P boxes of capacity A and *x-k* balls from the Q bins with capacity B. Use stars and bars approach on each side to calculate the number of ways to pick *k,x-k* respectively, and multiply to get the total. (Considering of course that you can only do that when both *k,x-k* do not exceed the capacities A,B).

To not consider the cases where k>A and x-k>B you have to implement the formula below

[image]

Which counts all combinations in which *n* items are allocated to *k* bins, excluding combinations where at least one bin contains more than C items.
In your case you need to use this formula twice, once to allocate *k* balls to P bins with capacity A, and once to allocate *x-k* balls to Q bins with capacity B.
Then the multiplication should give you the correct result.

Comment: This is wrong in many ways.First of all, it doesn't satisfy the at least constraint and secondly this will not work for large value of p,a,q and b

Comment: suppose there are 2 bags p having capacity 2 balls and 1 bag q having capacity 2 balls then the number of ways to select at least 3 balls would be 7( for selecting 3 balls)+6(for selecting 4 balls)+3(for selecting 5 balls) and 1(selecting all the balls)=17

Comment: Now what you can do is first make a list of total balls we have in p bag which in this case is equal to 4 and for q it is 2.so array1=[1,1,1,1] and array2=[1,1] now to select 3 balls I will first look into the array1 here I can choose ball in 4 choose 3 ways which are equal to 4 and from array2 alone I can't choose 3 balls but from arra1+array2 i can choose ball in 2 ways(exclusive) by choosing index 1 in frst  case and index 2 in another case and I can also choose both the indices.Now the total comes out to be 7 for choosing exactly 3 balls.same method can be applied for 4,5 and 6 .

Comment: It satisfies the at least constraint , see first line....although it is wrong in the condition of k>A since we need to accept combinations when k<P*A and similarly for x-k<Q*B and disqualify cases where k>A and x-k>B.

Comment: That is what I am saying this will give the wrong answer for 4,5 and 6.